# derived column in Order by in partition

Tags: t-sql, sql-order-by, case, partition

Using Sql Server 2008 R2.

Where there is more than 1 row of type demographic change, I need to delete all but 1 per person, but the types of demographic changes are weighted, with some more important than others. I don't know what the data will hold but if a more important one exists for a particular Contact, I want it to rise to the top.

I tried:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT lastname, firstname, FieldChanged,
     Case 'FieldChanged'
     When 'firstname' then 0
     When 'lastname' then 0
     When 'ssn' then 1
     When 'xyz' then 5
       End as "Weight"
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY D2.ContactId, D2.ContractId ORDER BY weight asc) AS demorow
    FROM MyDATA d2
    where d2.FieldChanged in ('firstname', 'lastname', 'ssn', 'xyz')
)
SELECT *
FROM cte 
WHERE demorow > 1
```

This gives me an error: Invalid column name 'weight'. 
I think I can't use APPLY since there's no unique key in the source table, which is not under my control.

Update:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MyTempTable
```

(firstname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    lastname varchar(25) NOT NULL,
    FieldChanged varchar(25),
    ContactId uniqueidentifier,
    ContractId uniqueidentifier
  )
GO
Insert into dbo.mytemptable
(firstname ,
    lastname ,
    FieldChanged ,
    ContactId ,
    ContractId)
    Values
    ('john', 'smith', 'ssn', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070201', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070202')
   , ('john', 'smith', 'xyz', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070201', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070202')
   , ('mary', 'doe', 'xyz', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070203', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070202')
   , ('mary', 'doe', 'firstname', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070203', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070202')
   , ('mary', 'doe', 'lastname', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070203', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070202')
   , ('mary', 'doe', 'ssn', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070203', '688CB150-C7FD-E511-8709-00155D070202')

For this data I'd want John Smith's and Mary Doe's respective xyz rows to be selected, as less important than their name change rows.

Update 2:

I think this works:

```
;WITH cte AS
```

(
    SELECT lastname, firstname, FieldChanged,
     Case FieldChanged
         When 'firstname' then 0
         When 'lastname' then 0
         When 'ssn' then 5
         When 'xyz' then 1
         else 9
     End as "Weight",
    ContactId, ContractID
    FROM edi..MyDATA  d2
    where d2.FieldChanged in ('firstname', 'lastname', 'ce_ssn', 'Policy Number')
),
cte2 As
(
    SELECT *
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContactId, ContractId ORDER BY weight asc) AS demorow
    FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE demorow > 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column aliases are assigned after all of the other clauses of a SELECT expression are executed (except for ORDER BY *clauses*, but *not* ORDER BY *expressions*), so you cannot use them within the same SELECT expression, only outside of them (or in an ORDER BY *clause*).

Here's a quick fix:

```
;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT lastname, firstname, FieldChanged,
     Case FieldChanged
     When 'firstname' then 0
     When 'lastname' then 0
     When 'ssn' then 1
     When 'xyz' then 5
       End as "Weight",
    ContactId, ContractID
    FROM MyDATA d2
    where d2.FieldChanged in ('firstname', 'lastname', 'ssn', 'xyz')
),
cte2 As
(
    SELECT *
     , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ContactId, ContractId ORDER BY weight asc) AS demorow
    FROM cte
)
SELECT *
FROM cte2
WHERE demorow > 1
```

Comment: At first I thought your suggestion would work for me but when I exchanged the weights on 2 cases where I knew I had 2 rows for a single person, the same row was selected.

Comment: @DeveloperM That's a different problem.  You would have to give us some sample data that demonstrated the problem.

Comment: I will edit my original post with some data and further explanation. Sorry I wasn't clear.

Comment: I think I've got it. Thank you for your suggestion. Putting the case statement variable in quote was a mistake I believe. I've posted my final (?) query above.

Comment: @DeveloperM Ah yes, I did miss that.  Fixed now.

Comment: Another requirement: if a person has only 1 demo change I don't want to select it. That is I will be deleting all rows identified by the query, leaving at most 1 row per person.  When I changed the IN clause to FieldChanged Is Not Null, to include all types of changes, many more rows came up and they were rows for people who only had a single demo change.

Comment: @DeveloperM You should post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 1):

replace "weight" in the order by with the full CASE statement. Or put the main query (without order by) in a sub query and the row number in the outer query. YOu should then be able to access the "weight" column in order by.